# Windows Phone 7: Should I be adding new Pages or changing the visibility of Grids to switch between different forms?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I’ve tried to word the title the best I could but what I’m trying to achieve is that on the MainPage.xaml  I have a button and then ideally I want to go to NewPage.xaml .

Now is this possible or I am completely on the wrong wave length and if so could someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's best to use the navigation service to navigate to a new page so that when the user presses the Back button they automatically get sent back to the previous page (as expected).

Comment: I guess for what I'm doing using the Navigation Service to Navigate btween the three pages is fine.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you're going to do, really. The MSDN ["Application Page Model For Windows Phone"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg278407%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) page has a pretty good description of when it's appropriate to use a different page and when it's not.

It's generally about a page representing part of a navigation stack, ideally representing some user-identifiable step (e.g. looking at the details of an item, or possibly performing a search). I agree it's not always clearcut though.

Comment: Agreed. My general rule of thumb is Grid for "glorified messageBoxes", new Page for everything else.

Answer (score 0):

This is one of those do I use the framework or go it on my own questions.

By going with the framework you get some heavy lifting done for you (such as back key handling) at the cost of staying within the frameworks boundaries. You're also more likely to have your code considered when the platform considers make changes that potentially break some code.

By not going with the framework you get greater flexibility at the cost of doing more heavy lifting and potentially having your model broken by future releases. You're also more likely to hit surprises that are catered for by the framework path.

With all that said, some people have been doing what you suggest as an alternative to using NavigationService. One of the walls they hit is complexity. The other is the page load gets very heavy by having multiple pages declared up front.

The link Jon pointed you to is a good guide, as is Peter Torr's post on a related topic.

[Introducing the concept of “Places” - Peter Torr's Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ptorr/archive/2010/08/28/introducing-the-concept-of-places.aspx)